# Regular Expression in C# and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement regular express for below condition , can any one help please

```
Numeric 0-9 with special character/ \ @ # $ % ^ & * ! - ~ . _ ( ) & space allowed


like : 123abc not allowed
like : 123#$%~. are allowed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've pretty much wrote the regular expression yourself, you need to add those characters to a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with proper escaping, use a [quantifier](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) and [anchor](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html) your expression.

```
^[0-9/\\@#$%^&*!~._() -]+$
```

In C#, you can use the [`Regex.IsMatch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to validate:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[0-9/\\@#$%^&*!~._() -]+$")) { ... }
```

In JS, you can use the [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method to validate:

```
var re = /^[0-9/\\@#$%^&*!~._() -]+$/
if (re.test(input)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
^[0-9!@#$%^&~*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*$
```

[Here is working example](https://regex101.com/r/qJ7xK8/34)

Answer (score 1):

For the regex itself, you should be able to pretty much list the allowed characters in square brackets:

```
^[0-9/\\@#$%^&*!-~._()\ ]*$
```

Use * at the end (before the trailing $) to match 0 or more characters (i.e. if empty string is OK), or use + at the end (before the trailing $) to match 1 or more characters.

Depending on the language / regex implementation, you might need to escape more of those characters within the pattern string.

Comment: Thanks Paul for quick reply. it's taking alphabets value also like a,b,c,d....I want to disabled alphabets.

Comment: OK, so you want to match the full input.  I've edited my answer above to include ^ at the beginning and $ at the end.